# tax calculation program is returning 0.00 to c++ output stream for file

Tags: c++

I have just done the calculation for the school assignment, The below code always return **0.00** for every variable:

```
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    ifstream inData;

    ofstream outData;

    double  hourPay;

        double weekOne, weekTwo, weekThree, weekFour, weekFive;

    double incomeBfrTax, netIncome, clothAndAcc, schlSupplies, savingBond, parentSavingBond, tax;

    inData.open("test.txt");

    outData.open("calcRecieve.out");

    outData << fixed << showpoint;

    outData << setprecision(2); //Step 4

    inData >> hourPay >> weekOne >> weekTwo >> weekThree >> weekFour >> weekFive;

    outData << hourPay << weekOne << weekTwo << weekThree << weekFour << weekFive;

    weekOne = weekOne * hourPay;

    weekTwo *= hourPay;

    weekThree *= hourPay;

    weekFour *= hourPay;

    incomeBfrTax = weekOne + weekTwo + weekThree + weekFour;

    tax = 14 / 100 * incomeBfrTax;

    netIncome = incomeBfrTax - tax;

    clothAndAcc = 10 / 100 * netIncome;

    schlSupplies = 1 / 100 * netIncome;

    savingBond = netIncome - (schlSupplies + clothAndAcc);

    savingBond = 25 / 100 * savingBond;

    for (int i = 0; i < savingBond; i++) {

        parentSavingBond += .50;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the code it only returns 0.00 for every outData stream. I am pretty sure that there are many flaws in my calculation. the values in test.txt file are:
*15.50 40.00 35.00 40.00 37.00 40.00*

Comment: You should put output statements for each calculation, so at the very least you know where the mistakes start to occur.  Also there is no need for double spacing the program -- it just makes the code harder to read due to having to scroll the window.

Comment: Note that the division `/` has higher precedence than multiplication, so something like `1 / 2 * x` will be evaluated as `(1 / 2) * x` and since the numerator and denominator are both integers, the quotient will be converted to an integer. You probably want to enclose the denominator in parenthesis to prevent that.

Comment: Note that: 10 / 100 is 0.

Comment: Stuff like `14 / 100` will get truncated because both operands are integers. Use something like `14.0 / 100` or just `0.14`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's incorrect. Division [has the same precedence as multiplication](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), but they have left-to-right associativity.